# Finding a set of edges to add to a set of graphs to satisfy connectivity constraints

Tags: graph-theory, z3, smt, z3py, sat

I have a set of N undirected, disconnected graphs that share the same M vertices, but have different edges. I also have a set of constraints for each graph of the form "V<sub>0</sub> is connected to V<sub>1</sub>" or "V<sub>3</sub> is not connected to V<sub>5</sub>" etc.

I want to find a set of edges such that adding those edges to every graph causes every graph to satisfy its constraints.

For a simple example, consider, for two given graphs with vertices V<sub>0</sub>, V<sub>1</sub>, V<sub>2</sub>, V<sub>3</sub>, V<sub>4</sub>:

- a graph G with one edge (V<sub>0</sub>, V<sub>1</sub>) and the constraint "V<sub>0</sub> is connected to V<sub>2</sub>"
- a graph H with edge (V<sub>1</sub>, V<sub>3</sub>) and the constraints "V<sub>2</sub> is connected to V<sub>4</sub>", "V<sub>0</sub> is **not** connected to V<sub>2</sub>"

With these given parameters, the problem is satisfiable by adding the edges {(V<sub>1</sub>, V<sub>2</sub>), (V<sub>3</sub>, V<sub>4</sub>)} to both of the graphs.

---

After failing to solve the problem with a script, I reached for z3 to help, but I've run into trouble trying to express connectivity. My current solution consists of an unquantified formula with only boolean terms:

- c<sub>i,j,k</sub> for each pair of vertices *i, j* representing whether they are connected in graph *k* with added edges from the solution
- g<sub>i,j,k</sub> for each pair of vertices *i, j* representing whether the edge between them is given in graph *k*
- s<sub>i,j</sub> for each pair of vertices *i, j* representing whether adding an edge between them is part of the solution

and assertions:

- g<sub>i,j,k</sub> if the edge (*i, j*) is given in graph *k*
- ¬g<sub>i,j,k</sub> if the edge (*i, j*) is *not* given in graph *k*
- c<sub>i,j,k</sub> if the graph *k* requires *i* and *j* to be connected
- ¬s<sub>i,j</sub> ∧ ¬c<sub>i,j,k</sub> if the graph *k* requires *i* and *j* to *not* be connected
- s<sub>i,j</sub> ⇒ c<sub>i,j,k</sub> for all graphs *k*
- c<sub>i,j,k</sub> = s<sub>i,j</sub> ∨ g<sub>i,j,k</sub> ∨ ((s<sub>i,z</sub> ∨ g<sub>i,z,k</sub>) ∧ c<sub>z,j,k</sub>) for all vertices *i, j, z* and graphs *k*

The last clause, however, does not seem to work as intended for expressing connectivity and z3 is returning `sat` but the clearly necessary s<sub>i,j</sub> are false in the resulting model.

Here's the shortest I could manage to make a minimal example of the problem:

```py
from itertools import combinations

from z3 import *

vertices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
edges = [tuple(sorted(edge)) for edge in list(combinations(vertices, 2))]

graphs = {
    "G": [(0, 1)],
    "H": [(1, 3)],
}

facts = Solver()

connected_in_graph = {}
for graph in graphs:
    for edge in edges:
        connected_in_graph[(graph, edge)] = Bool(f"{edge}_conn_in_{graph}")

solution_edges = {}
graph_given_edges = {}
for edge in edges:
    edge_in_solution = Bool(f"{edge}_in_solution")
    solution_edges[edge] = edge_in_solution
    for graph in graphs:
        given = Bool(f"{graph}_{edge}_given")
        graph_given_edges[(graph, edge)] = given
        if edge in graphs[graph]:
            facts.append(given)
        else:
            facts.append(Not(given))

facts.append(
    connected_in_graph[("G", (0, 2))],
    connected_in_graph[("H", (2, 4))],
    Not(connected_in_graph[("H", (0, 2))]),
)

for edge in edges:
    for graph in graphs:
        ors = [
            solution_edges[edge],
            graph_given_edges[(graph, edge)],
        ]
        for vertex in vertices:
            if vertex in edge:
                continue
            l_edge = tuple(sorted((edge[0], vertex)))
            r_edge = tuple(sorted((edge[1], vertex)))
            ors.append(
                And(
                    Or(
                        solution_edges[l_edge],
                        graph_given_edges[(graph, l_edge)],
                    ),
                    connected_in_graph[(graph, r_edge)],
                )
            )
        facts.append(connected_in_graph[(graph, edge)] == Or(*ors))

print(facts.check())
model = facts.model()
for edge in edges:
    c = solution_edges[edge]
    if model[c]:
        print(c)
```

I suppose what I'd actually need to express, rather than that last constraint, is relations:

c2(*i*, *j*, *k*, *through*) = s<sub>i,j</sub> ∨ g<sub>i,j,k</sub> ∨ (∃z. z ∉ (ignored ∪ {i, j}) ∧ (s<sub>i,z</sub> ∨ g<sub>i,z,k</sub>) ∧ c(z, j, k, ignored ∪ {i}))

c(*i*, *j*, *k*) = c2(*i*, *j*, *k*, {})

However, reducing that to just unquantified boolean terms would obviously take somewhere on the order of M! time and space.

Is there a better way of expressing the existence of a path in a graph in SAT/SMT, or perhaps a better way of solving this problem altogether?

---

Alias's suggestion to use transitive closure seems to be the solution to this, but I seem to have trouble using it properly. My revised code:

```py
from itertools import combinations

from z3 import *

vertices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
edges = [tuple(sorted(edge)) for edge in list(combinations(vertices, 2))]

graphs = {
    "G": [(0, 1)],
    "H": [(1, 3)],
}

facts = Solver()

vs = {}
VertexSort = DeclareSort("VertexSort")
for vertex in vertices:
    vs[vertex] = Const(f"V{vertex}", VertexSort)
facts.add(Distinct(*vs.values()))

given = {}
directly_connected = {}
tc_connected = {}
for graph in graphs:
    given[graph] = Function(
        f"{graph}_given", VertexSort, VertexSort, BoolSort()
    )
    directly_connected[graph] = Function(
        f"directly_connected_{graph}", VertexSort, VertexSort, BoolSort()
    )
    tc_connected[graph] = TransitiveClosure(directly_connected[graph])

in_solution = Function("in_solution", VertexSort, VertexSort, BoolSort())


for edge in edges:
    # commutativity
    facts.add(
        in_solution(vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])
        == in_solution(vs[edge[1]], vs[edge[0]])
    )
    for graph in graphs:
        # commutativity
        facts.add(
            given[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])
            == given[graph](vs[edge[1]], vs[edge[0]])
        )
        facts.add(
            directly_connected[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])
            == directly_connected[graph](vs[edge[1]], vs[edge[0]])
        )
        # definition of direct connection
        facts.add(
            directly_connected[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])
            == Or(
                in_solution(vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]]),
                given[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]]),
            ),
        )
        if edge in graphs[graph]:
            facts.add(given[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]]))
        else:
            facts.add(Not(given[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])))


facts.append(
    tc_connected["G"](vs[0], vs[2]),
    tc_connected["H"](vs[2], vs[4]),
    Not(tc_connected["H"](vs[0], vs[2])),
)

print(facts.check())
model = facts.model()
print(model)
print(f"solution: {model[in_solution]}")
```

Prints `sat` but finds the definition `in_solution = [else -> False]` rather than the solution I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to look at the transitive-closure for expressing connectedness. See https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-transitive-closure. Note that for transitive-closure to work,  relations should be declared over uninterpreted sorts. Since you have a finite graph you should be able to do that by declaring the relevant objects for your vertices and asserting that they are `distinct`. Let me know how it goes if you pursue this path: Transitive-closure code in z3 hasn't been the most well-tested, but I think it can handle this particular case.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @alias, this seems to be the right way to tackle this! Unfortunately, I suspect I'm missing something simple, because after rewriting my code to use transitive-closure and uninterpreted sorts the resulting model has `in_solution = [else -> False]`. I've revised my question with the updated code.

Comment: You might want to print the solver object in SMTLib to see if what it generates looks reasonable to you (`print(facts.sexpr())`). Python is nice, but sometimes it can introduce a layer of indirection and generate code that you didn't intend. Is that the case?

Comment: In this case the problem wasn't the generated SMTLib problem, but my misunderstanding of uninterpreted sorts. Making VertexSort an enumeration type rather than an uninterpreted sort made the solver work and return correct results for all of my test cases - thank you for your help!

Comment: Fantastic! Please post your final "answer" as a solution and accept it here at stack-overflow. (You can accept your own answers.) This can help future readers greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [@alias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936310/alias) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72275312/finding-a-set-of-edges-to-add-to-a-set-of-graphs-to-satisfy-connectivity-constra?noredirect=1#comment127692070_72275312), solving the problem was made possible by using [transitive closures](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-transitive-closure).

By:

- defining relations *given<sub>G</sub>(v1, v2)* and *directly_connected<sub>G</sub>(v1, v2)* for each graph *G* and a relation *in_solution(v1, v2)* where *v1, v2* are of an enumeration type with constructors for each vertex
- asserting *directly_connected<sub>G</sub>(v1, v2) = in_solution(v1,
  v2) ∨ given<sub>G</sub>(v1, v2)* for each *v1*, *v2*
- declaring a transitive closure *TC_connected<sub>G</sub>(v1, v2)* for each graph G
- asserting constraints in terms of *TC_connected*

I got the solver to return a correct solution for all of my test cases.

The revised code:

```py
from itertools import combinations

from z3 import *

vertices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
edges = [tuple(sorted(edge)) for edge in list(combinations(vertices, 2))]

graphs = {
    "G": [(0, 1)],
    "H": [(1, 3)],
}

facts = Solver()


VertexSort = Datatype("VertexSort")
for vertex in vertices:
    VertexSort.declare(str(vertex))
VertexSort = VertexSort.create()

vs = {}
for vertex in vertices:
    vs[vertex] = getattr(VertexSort, str(vertex))


given = {}
directly_connected = {}
tc_connected = {}
for graph in graphs:
    given[graph] = Function(
        f"{graph}_given", VertexSort, VertexSort, BoolSort()
    )
    directly_connected[graph] = Function(
        f"directly_connected_{graph}", VertexSort, VertexSort, BoolSort()
    )
    tc_connected[graph] = TransitiveClosure(directly_connected[graph])

in_solution = Function("in_solution", VertexSort, VertexSort, BoolSort())


for edge in edges:
    # commutativity
    facts.add(
        in_solution(vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])
        == in_solution(vs[edge[1]], vs[edge[0]])
    )
    for graph in graphs:
        # commutativity
        facts.add(
            given[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])
            == given[graph](vs[edge[1]], vs[edge[0]])
        )
        facts.add(
            directly_connected[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])
            == directly_connected[graph](vs[edge[1]], vs[edge[0]])
        )
        # definition of direct connection
        facts.add(
            directly_connected[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])
            == Or(
                in_solution(vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]]),
                given[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]]),
            ),
        )
        if edge in graphs[graph]:
            facts.add(given[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]]))
        else:
            facts.add(Not(given[graph](vs[edge[0]], vs[edge[1]])))


facts.append(
    tc_connected["G"](vs[0], vs[2]),
    tc_connected["H"](vs[2], vs[4]),
    Not(tc_connected["H"](vs[0], vs[2])),
)

print(facts.check())
model = facts.model()
print(f"solution: {model[in_solution]}")
```